# In Python adding an error bar as a percentage of x,y data using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to add error bars to 2 series of data in a scatter plot. The problem is that I would like the error bar to represent a percentage of the x,y data for each data point so for example on the x axis the error bar is 10 % of each data point. Is there a way in the ax.errorbar code to do this? or must I work out it for each data point manually then add it in as the error?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pylab import rcParams

#data
x1 = [11,20,25,80]
y1 = [15,35,50,90]
x2 = [25,36,58,63]
y2 = [30,40,68,78]

#error in percentage
yerr=5
xerr=10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 5
#Sm vs La

#mafic data
ax.scatter(x1,y1,color='b',marker='D',s=50,label='Phase V m')
#andesite data
ax.scatter(x2,y2,color='c',s=50,label='Phase V a')
ax.set_ylabel('Sm (ppm)',fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('La (ppm)',fontsize=14)
plt.legend(loc='lower right',scatterpoints=1)
#error bar 
ax.errorbar(x1,y1,yerr,xerr,color='black',barsabove='False')
ax.errorbar(x2,y2,yerr,xerr,color='black',barsabove='False')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The errorbar function has no option for that, but you can easily do that yourself. I would suggest to convert the lists with your data to numpy arrays so you can easily multiply them:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data
x1 = np.array([11,20,25,80])
y1 = np.array([15,35,50,90])
x2 = np.array([25,36,58,63])
y2 = np.array([30,40,68,78])

#error in percentage
yerr=5
xerr=10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

#mafic data
ax.scatter(x1, y1, color='b', marker='D', s=50, label='Phase V m')
#andesite data
ax.scatter(x2, y2, color='c', s=50, label='Phase V a')
ax.set_ylabel('Sm (ppm)', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('La (ppm)', fontsize=14)
plt.legend(loc='lower right', scatterpoints=1)
#error bar 
ax.errorbar(x1, y1, x1*xerr/100., y1*yerr/100., color='black', barsabove='False')
ax.errorbar(x2, y2, x2*xerr/100., y2*yerr/100., color='black', barsabove='False')

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: @Geo does that answer you question?